# How to create a menu like LinkedIn App

Tags: android

How to create The "Updates You Inbox MOre" menu like in LinkedIn app

in Android?

like this
http://www.blackberryos.com/bbos-images/2011/LinkedIn-iwc.jpg

Comment: Try tabs? Figure it out!

Comment: That is not tabs.... when i click in the linkedin logo the menu appears on top of other layout...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out...

needs to create a frame layout and implements onCLickLIstener on the button
onclick inflate layout